# Sequelize query error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am building a quiz app with Node. I have two models in postgres, "Quizes" and "Questions." Quizes have many questions. I want to query all quizes with their questions. I am getting an odd error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column questions.questions_id does not exist
```

I do not know why it is looking for a column called questions_id. That's not in my models. Here are both models:

Quiz model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize'); 

const {sequelize} = require('../db/sequelize'); 

const Quiz = sequelize.define('Quiz', 
    {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER, 
            primaryKey: true, 
            autoIncrement: true
        }, 
        title: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING, 
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, 
    {
        tableName: 'quizes',
        timestamps: false,
        underscored: true
    }
);

Quiz.associate = function(models) {
    Quiz.hasMany(
        models.Question, 
        {
            as: 'questions', 
            foreignKey: { allowNull: false }, 
            onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        }
    )
}

module.exports = {
    Quiz
}
```

Question model:

```
'use strict'; 

const Sequelize = require('sequelize'); 

const {sequelize} = require('../db/sequelize'); 

const Question = sequelize.define('Quiz', 
    {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER, 
            primaryKey: true, 
            autoIncrement: true
        }, 
        question: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING, 
            allowNull: false
        }, 
        answer_one: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING, 
            allowNull: true
        }, 
        answer_two: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING, 
            allowNull: true
        }, 
        answer_three: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING, 
            allowNull: true
        }, 
        answer_four: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING, 
            allowNull: true
        }, 
        correct_answer: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING, 
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
            tableName: 'questions', 
            timestamps: false, 
            underscored: true
    });  


Question.associate = function(models) {
    Question.belongsTo(
        models.Quiz, 
        {
            as: 'questions', 
            foreignKey: { allowNull: false }, 
            onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        }
    ); 
}

module.exports = {
    Question
}
```

The route that throws the error:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => Quiz.findAll(
    {
      limit: 50, 
      include: [{
          model: Question, 
          as: 'questions'
      }]
    })
    .then(quizes => res.json({
      quizes
    }))
);
```

My SQL migration:

```
BEGIN;  

CREATE TABLE quizes (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title TEXT NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE questions (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    question TEXT NOT NULL,
    answer_one TEXT,  
    answer_two TEXT, 
    answer_three TEXT, 
    answer_four TEXT, 
    correct_answer TEXT NOT NULL, 
    quiz_id INTEGER REFERENCES quizes ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL
); 

INSERT INTO quizes (title) VALUES ('Mercury');
INSERT INTO quizes (title) VALUES ('Venus');
INSERT INTO quizes (title) VALUES ('Earth');
INSERT INTO quizes (title) VALUES ('Mars');
INSERT INTO quizes (title) VALUES ('Jupiter');
INSERT INTO quizes (title) VALUES ('Saturn');
INSERT INTO quizes (title) VALUES ('Uranus');
INSERT INTO quizes (title) VALUES ('Neptune');
INSERT INTO questions (question, answer_one, answer_two, answer_three, answer_four, correct_answer, quiz_id) VALUES ('What is Venues', 'A moon', 'A star', 'A planet', 'An asteroid', 'A planet', 1);

COMMIT;
```

Comment: In your migration for `Question`, did you define a foreign key to the `Quiz` model?

Comment: Will you please check the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your assosiation should look like this :

```
Quiz.hasMany(
    models.Question, 
    {
        as: 'questions', 
        foreignKey: 'quiz_id',  // You need to define the foreign key
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    }
)

Question.belongsTo(
    models.Quiz, 
    {
        as: 'questions', 
        foreignKey: 'quiz_id',  // You need to define the foreign key
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    }
);
```